# jQuery IE8 Object required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a button, that when clicked is supposed to open a jQuery UI Dialog. It works in FF3, FF4, Chrome, and IE8 with ChromeFrame. It does not work in normal IE8. I get an error that simply says "Object required". Below is the function the click calls.

```
function punchNonProd()
{
    var HTML = "";
    HTML += "<tr id='burdenLine'><td><strong>Description</strong></td><td><input class='ui-corner-all' type='text' id='diaNP' size='12'></td></tr>";
    HTML += "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><span class='button' onClick='sendPunch(\"NONPROD\", $(\"#diaNP\").val(), $(\"#loadedMech\").val());'>Use Description</span></td></tr>";
    HTML += "</table>";

    $("#dialogSmall").dialog("option", "title", 'Non-Billable Punch')
                     .html(HTML)
                     .dialog("option", "width", 800)
                     .dialog("open")
                     .dialog("option", "position", "center")
                     .dialog( "option", "buttons", { "Kochtinuous": function() { punchKochImpr(); },
                                                     "Break": function() { sendPunch("NONPROD", "BREAK", $("#loadedMech").val(), isLeader); },
                                                     "Clean Up": function() { sendPunch("NONPROD", "CLEAN_UP", $("#loadedMech").val(), isLeader); },
                                                     "Huddle": function() { sendPunch("NONPROD", "HUDDLE", $("#loadedMech").val(), isLeader); },
                                                     "Meeting": function() { sendPunch("NONPROD", "MEETING", $("#loadedMech").val(), isLeader);} } );
    loadDefaults();
}
```

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.4, and jQuery 1.4.2

The error occurs on line 4481 of the uncompressed jQuery file.

***UPDATE***

I was able to figure out that the problem comes from the command `$("#dialogSmall").html(HTML);`. I am still trying to figure out why this happens.

Comment: Are the multiple instances of .dialog() tripping it up? Maybe you can try rolling them into one.

Comment: @orolo I have other places that have multiples and it handles them without problem.

Comment: You should work back up the call stack and find what line in your code is causing the problem.  Something is null or undefined for that message to come up, something that jQuery expects to be there.  Is buttonset() a method that's defined for instance?

Comment: @flatline Thank you for pointing out th buttonset. I guess I had glanced over that. I shouldn't have been calling that. However that was not my problem. I am trying to work my way up the call stack, I am unfortunately having issues with IE not waning to go into my function.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. Put this into jsfiddle.net for us. Everything is so ambiguous, we have no context for your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HTML` variable does not contain valid HTML. It may help if you add the missing tags.

Comment: I think you're right. He's probably loaded the HTML variable in like it's global or something then lost it's scope... But I don't see how that will result in an error of the jQuery Library, it should just render a sloppy DOM.

Comment: This was it. The missing `<table>` was the entire problem. I did a bit more looking at the jQuery that was throwing errors and now I can say with certainty that it was occurring when converting the string into DOM objects. Thank you very much Álvaro G. Vicario